# monaco-editor: hide overview ruler

Tags: monaco-editor

Is there a way to completely hide overview ruler in monaco-editor? It is still visible with the following:

```
        overviewRulerLanes: 0,
        hideCursorInOverviewRuler: true,
        scrollbar: {
            vertical: 'hidden'
        },
        overviewRulerBorder: false,
```

Answer (score 10):

Did you mean [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Abn7a.png)?

if so:

`minimap: {enabled: false}`

Comment: No, I mean the scrollbar, not the minimap

Comment: to hide the minimap needs to been in the options object. options={{ minimap: { enabled: false } }}

Answer (score 7):

If you want to hide the scroll bar, you can do this

```js
const monacoInstance=monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("editor"),{
    value:`console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");console.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");\nconsole.log("hello,world");`,
    language:"javascript",
    // theme:"vs-dark",
    readOnly:true,
    minimap:{enabled:false},
    overviewRulerLanes: 0,
    scrollbar: {
        vertical:"hidden",
        horizontal: "hidden",
        handleMouseWheel:false,
    },
    wordWrap: 'on',
})
```

Comment: I am using it like this

<Editor
                        height="80vh"
                        defaultLanguage="javascript"
                        defaultValue= {code}
                        className=" overflow-hidden"
                    />

How to solve this issue in react js.

Comment: @AnkitKumar pass the same options to the options prop like so: <Editor ... options={{ scrollbar:{...} }}

Answer (score 4):

With the settings you are posting, it should work

```cs
        overviewRulerLanes: 0,
        hideCursorInOverviewRuler: true,
        scrollbar: {
            vertical: 'hidden'
        },
        overviewRulerBorder: false,
```